# Redirect with lighttpd

Tags: redirect, ssl, lighttpd

I'm trying to do this:

https://dummiesite.com --> http://dummiesite.com

and

http://dummiesite.com  --> http://new.dummiesite.com

and

http://new.dummiesite.com --> https://new.dummiesite.com

So no matter what site the user goes, it will allways be redirected to https://new.dummiesite.com

The problem:

With I have a wildcard certificate for *.site.com. But it is only valid for all the subdomains of site.com, not for site.com itself. With lighttpd I cannot use more than one certificate per IP (I have only one), so when the user goes to https://dummiesite.com, it gets an error because the certificate is not valid.

That is why I'm trying to redirect https://dummiesite.com to http://dummiesite.com. How can I do it without a valid certificate and without showing the user errors?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't with the current certificate. HTTPS is HTTP inside an SSL tunnel, so before you can do the redirect at the HTTP level the SSL connection has to be established. But this fails because your certificate does not match the hostname. You need to get a certificate which includes both *.dummiesite.com and dummiesite.com (yes, this is possible).